# Character discovers anti gravity emitters, flies a shipping container into space and docks with space station

Tags: story-identification

In this story, a character discovers anti gravity emitters, flies a shipping container into space and docks with space station.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Comment: What is that? A book, a short story, a movie? Please [edit] your question to clarify - we can't really guess, and I'm afraid that with no media, this might be a bit broad... :/

Comment: Voting to leave open since we probably have the correct answer already.

Comment: I'm certain I've identified the work based on the sufficiently distinctive details that the original poster provided, yet people are still voting to close the question without giving the reasons for their votes. That's frustrating, to say the least.

Comment: @Gaultheria in all fairness when you're presented with just the one-liner in First Posts review, and not shown any answers, that does look too broad (hence my comment and my vote, but I'm only speaking for myself, not for others)

Comment: @Jenayah — You wrote your comment requesting details — and presumably cast your vote at the same time — around the time that I wrote my answer, and I'm totally okay with that. It's the close votes that people cast after I posted my answer that I find surprising.

Comment: @Gaultheria the work has not been identified as correct so there is no way of knowing you’re right at the moment. Someone else could come along and post something that also looks just as correct as you. Just because it looks like your answer may be correct doesn’t mean it is and so until confirmed doesn’t change the nature of the question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot — Sure, but an exact match for some really specific and unusual details suggests that the question contains enough detail to be answerable.

Comment: If a question is closed for lacking detail, and an answer turns out to be correct, does someone need to add detail to the question before the original poster can accept the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [*Galactic Startup*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38726199-galactic-startup) (2018), by [Brian Whiting](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/17739453.Brian_Whiting)

In *Galactic Startup*, the opening novel in a series of the same name, a group of young adult friends promote their new spaceflight company and test their invention of an antigravity drive by flying a shipping container to the International Space Station.

> Alex and his three friends drop out of college after discovering a revolutionary way to travel into space using a small amount of energy. Their world-changing technology is sought by the government, and they are forced to go into hiding while they perfect it. Their adventures into orbit and beyond become a global sensation. As they navigate fame, family and those who are determined to stop them, little do they know that their little startup could have galactic consequences once they discover a derelict spaceship.
>
> — Goodreads: [*Galactic Startup*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38726199-galactic-startup)

As of 2019, there are 3 novels in the [*Galactic Startup* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/258240-galactic-startup):

1. [*Galactic Startup*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38726199-galactic-startup) (2018)
2. [*Neighbors*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41197131-neighbors) (2018)
3. [*Shadows*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44428709-shadows) (2019)

[image: Cover of Galactic Startup]
[image: Cover of Neighbors]
[image: Cover of Shadows]

Comment: From a following review: "...you might need either a good air supply or heat in your converted shipping container. They don't question the wisdom of doing a drive by of the ISS..." so this does sound like an excellent match.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.